# How can I enjoy the Euro 2016 without having a ticket?

Tags: france, sports-events, events, football

The Euro 2016 is the European football championship that will be held in France from June, 16 to July, 16 this year. I will be in France (mostly in Paris, but I can move to other areas) during this period but tickets are expensive and were hard to get, so I cannot afford to buy one. However, I wish I could enjoy the "mood" of this special event when in France.

Are there any public events (festivals, parties, concerts,...) organized around the event?

Note that I am not asking for pubs that would broadcast the games (I can do it back home), but public outdoor broadcastings on big screen would be considered as an "event".

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I removed the *paris* tag though, since the question is  not restricted to Paris. The Euro games will be in several stadiums, and I guess there will be events in most major cities.

Answer (score 10):

[This official "Eiffel Tower Fan Zone"](http://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/major-events/france-welcomes-the-uefa-euro-2016/follow-the-euro-in-paris/the-eiffel-tower-fan-zone) in Paris might be exactly what you are looking for.

It is on Champ de Mars right in front of Eiffel tower, free of cost and beyond public viewing of matches it will feature concerts and other forms of entertainment (and probably lots of sponsoring).

For other cities you should be able to find similar events by hitting "euro 2016 public viewing [city name]" into the search engine of your preference.

Comment: There will be "Fan Zones" like this in every major city, so this is not limited to Paris.